# ST_Transform in PostGIS not working on Linux, GDAL 3.5.1, but working on MacOS, GDAL 3.5.3

Tags: postgis, gdal, proj, postgis-raster

I have a raster in PostGIS that has a non-standard projection, namely

```
 select srid,proj4text from spatial_ref_sys where srid=9822;
 srid |                                              proj4text                                              
------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 9822 | +proj=aea +lat_0=23 +lon_0=-96 +lat_1=29.5 +lat_2=45.5 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs
(1 row)
```

One of these rasters stored is

```
select ST_Metadata(rast) from wms_current where rid=1 limit 1;
                             st_metadata                             
---------------------------------------------------------------------
 (-2151863.8119731266,2391003.832999289,256,256,300,-300,0,0,9822,1)
(1 row)
```

ST_Transform produces different results on different systems.  The correct version, running PostGIS on MacOS:

```
select PostGIS_GDAL_Version();
      postgis_gdal_version       
---------------------------------
 GDAL 3.5.3, released 2022/10/21
(1 row)

select ST_Metadata(ST_Transform(rast, 4326)) from wms_current where rid=1 limit 1;
                                             st_metadata                                              
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 (-122.4263595659119,41.99724583808909,334,247,0.003420870401971163,-0.003420870401971163,0,0,4326,1)
(1 row)
```

On Linux:

```
select PostGIS_GDAL_Version();
      postgis_gdal_version       
---------------------------------
 GDAL 3.5.1, released 2022/06/30
(1 row)

select ST_Metadata(ST_Transform(rast, 4326)) from wms_current where rid=1 limit 1;
                                              st_metadata                                              
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 (-46.507427056342145,42.78351429782924,357,265,0.003601364596063967,-0.003601364596063967,0,0,4326,1)
(1 row)
```

The versions of PROJ seem to be the same on both systems. Is this a known bug with GDAL 3.5.1?

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out: the spatial_ref_sys table was different between the two.

What doesn't work:

```
select * from spatial_ref_sys where srid=9822;
 srid | auth_name | auth_srid | srtext |                                              proj4text                                              
------+-----------+-----------+--------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 9822 | EPSG      |      9822 |        | +proj=aea +lat_0=23 +lon_0=-96 +lat_1=29.5 +lat_2=45.5 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs
(1 row)
```

What does work:

```
select * from spatial_ref_sys where srid=9822;
 srid | auth_name | auth_srid | srtext |                                              proj4text                                              
------+-----------+-----------+--------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 9822 |           |           |        | +proj=aea +lat_0=23 +lon_0=-96 +lat_1=29.5 +lat_2=45.5 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs
(1 row)
```